# How to create dropdown programatically in php?

Tags: php, html

I want to create dropdown programmatically. The dropdown have time and at last I want in option close. Kindly check what I am doing:

```
<select>
     <?php for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++): ?>
      <option value="<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i % 12 ? $i % 12 : 12 ?>:00 <?= $i >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM' ?></option>
      <?php endfor ?>
</select>
```

This gives me the time what I want like
1:00 Am
2:00 AM

But I want at last the option "close" will show. Because office will close on sunday. I am getting the numbers programatically but at last I want user is able to select close option as well.

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: You shouldn't nest [ternary's](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) inside of eachother, it makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do the following, this will add the close option after your code has added the hours:

```
<select>
  <?php for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++): ?>
    <option value="<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i % 12 ? $i % 12 : 12 ?>:00 <?= $i >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM' ?></option>
  <?php endfor ?>
  <option value="close">Close</option>
</select>
```